# Renaming files by using a prefix from text file

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a set of files named

```
sample_exp_A1_A01
sample_exp_A2_A02
sample_exp_A3_A03
sample_exp_A4_A04
sample_exp_A5_A05
```

And I have a text file with the following values

```
A01 170
A02 186
A03 165
A04 130
A05 120
```

I would like to rename the files based on the text file values like

```
FS_170_sample_exp_A1_A01
FS_186_sample_exp_A2_A02
FS_165_sample_exp_A3_A03
FS_130_sample_exp_A4_A04
FS_120_sample_exp_A5_A05
```

So match the IDs in the text file based on `A01` or `A02` or `A03` or `A04` and then add that corresponding number as prefix to filenames. In addition also prefix all file names with a `FS` as shown above.

I manually tried doing it but could only do for one file at a time this way

```
rename 's/^/FS_170_/' *A01
```

to get

```
FS_170_sample_exp_A1_A01
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your suffixes are in a file named `suffix`, you can do this:

```
for fname in sample*; do
    echo mv "$fname" FS_"$(awk -v pf="${fname##*_}" \
        '$1 == pf {print $2}' suffix)"_"$fname"
done
```

It loops over all your files; in the loop, it puts together the new file name by prepending `FS_` and the output of

```
awk -v pf="${fname##*_}" '$1 == pf {print $2}' suffix
```

This assigns the last part of the input file name to the awk variable `pf`, and then, for lines in `suffix` where the first field matches that variable, prints the second field.

Alternatively, if you have a grep that supports Perl compatible regular expressions, you can use `grep -Po "${fname##*_} \K.*" suffix` instead (using a variable-sized look-behind, `\K`):

```
for fname in sample*; do
    echo mv "$fname" FS_"$(grep -Po "${fname##*_} \K.*" suffix)"_"$fname"
done
```

This is added to the new filename, and the rest of the new name is the complete old name.

For your input files, this results in

```
mv sample_exp_A1_A01 FS_170_sample_exp_A1_A01
mv sample_exp_A2_A02 FS_186_sample_exp_A2_A02
mv sample_exp_A3_A03 FS_165_sample_exp_A3_A03
mv sample_exp_A4_A04 FS_130_sample_exp_A4_A04
mv sample_exp_A5_A05 FS_120_sample_exp_A5_A05
```

To actually rename the files, the `echo` has to be removed.

---

If `suffix` is gigantic, you can accelerate this by having awk exit after the first match:

```
awk -v pf="${fname##*_}" '$1 == pf {print $2; exit}' suffix
```

or grep stop after the first match:

```
grep -m 1 -Po "${fname##*_} \K.*" suffix
```